# Locale switching in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react native app that supports both English & Arabic locale, my problem is that user locale is unknown until user log in to my app, my question is how can i switch locale from english to arabic when user is logging to my app without restarting my app.

my code for switching locale is :

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(!this.state.isRTL);
this.setState({isRTL: !this.state.isRTL});
// problem is that it requires restarting and i think restarting my app when user is logging in isn't a good practice.
```

anyone have a good solution or a recommendation on how to implement a good solution.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n